# Method always working before any other method

Tags: jsf

I want to get a database entity using a parameter from query string ,if i use a request scope bean i am doing this at postconstruct method and every thing ok but when i need a session bean

problem begin because i have not any method which working before any other methods.I want to what is most proper way doing this.Actually i need a method which working before any other method as  page_load of .net.I am using jsf 1.2  ,if you suggest phase listener is best choice please give me a generic example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define it as `actionListener` on all command links/buttons.

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.listener}" action="#{bean.action1}" />
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.listener}" action="#{bean.action2}" />
```

with

```
public void listener(ActionEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

It will get invoked *before* the action method.

The best approach, however, is to just use request scoped beans for form actions. If you need some session scoped data in the request scoped bean, then just inject it as `<managed-property>` in the request scoped one by `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: but this is not  a feasible way is it possible with phaselistener ,by the way i accept solution using request scoped bean with another session scoped bean.İf can i write a phase listener just before invoke aplication phase i will do what i need at here for all beans.